# How do I get DataSnapshot of only if a value is present?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have this database where I store user stuff. How do i get DataSnapshot only if uname is "user 1"
[Database image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP6qt.png)

Comment: Have you tried something so we can continue on?

Comment: try   .where(uname == "user 1")

Answer (score 0):

You need to query on realtime database. You can query by giving a ref:  `ref('uploads')`, order it by the field you want: `orderByChild('uname')` and then put your filter: `equalTo('user 1')`

```
firebase.database()
    .ref('uploads')
    .orderByChild('uname')
    .equalTo('user 1')
    .once('value')
    .then(snap => {
        snap.forEach(uploadSnap => {
            console.log(uploadSnap.val());
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

Comment: The provided solution does indeed work, but it for the web, while the OP is searching for a solution for Android.

Comment: Thats right. I didn't notice he put this detail in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get DataSnapshot only if uname is "user 1"

To be able to get elements from a Firebase Realtime Database where the "uname" property holds the value of "user 1", you need to use a query. To be sure that the DataSnapshot object you are looking for actually returns some results, then you should call [exists()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#exists()), as in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uploadsRef = rootRef.child("uploads");
Query queryByUserName = uploadsRef.orderByChild("uname").equalTo("user 1");
queryByUserName.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                if(userSnapshot.exists()) {
                    String uname = userSnapshot.child("uname").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", userSnapshot);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TA"G, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Since "user 1" already exists in the database, the result in the logcat will be:

```
user 1
```